# How to improve performance of this SELECT query JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which seems to be taking a long time to run on occasion. The slowness may be unrelated but I wanted to check what could be done to make this more efficient.

The user table has about 40k rows. The code table has about 30k rows. user_id and code are unique values.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user`, code 
WHERE `user`.user_id = code.user_id 
AND code.code = '50816ef96210415d1cad824bdb43';
```

I have an index setup on the code.user_id field. Anything else I can do? Should I have other indexes in place here?

Output from EXPLAIN on that query:

```
>> +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
>> | id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows  | Extra       |
>> +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
>> |  1 | SIMPLE      | code | ALL    | user_id       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 35696 | Using where | 
>> |  1 | SIMPLE      | user  | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | mydb.code.user_id |     1 |             | 
>> +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
>> 2 rows in set (10.11 sec)
```

Comment: Your question lacks detail. Is performance bad in some way? *Why* do you think that you need to optimize this particular query?

Comment: True. Added a bit more detail.

Comment: Based on the `EXPLAIN` output, mvp's suggestion to add an index on `code.code` is spot on.

Comment: Thx. A 'unique' index correct?

Comment: If you want to enforce that no two rows may have the same value in that column, then yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to add indexes on `code.code` and `user.user_id` fields, and it should start flying

Comment: It may not be that simple; the index on `code` may need to include both columns, in a particular order.

Comment: I think those I listed are really important, but code.user_id can be even dropped (not to say that I recommend that)

Comment: Since this query uses an implicit join, it's not quite that simple; the planner might decide to join `code` to `user` if it thinks that will be more efficient, and then you *would* want an index on `code.user_id`.

Comment: I highly doubt it in this particular case. code.code seems to be unique. That gives just one row from code table - index on code.user_id will not be used for sure

Answer (score 2):

Beside adding an index to code.code another thing you can do is to select only the columns you need ( i dont like using SELECT *  )